# Интресная задачка для jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Столкнулся с вопросом по скроллингу на `jQuery`.

Есть четыре блока каждый размером с экран, расположены один под другим. Если кликнуть по третьему то остальные сворачиваются. После этого на экране оказывается третий блок с возможностью развернуть остальные.
Разворачивать хотелось бы функцией `slideDown` или аналогичной ей.

Если просто её применить то при открытии остальных блоков третий уезжает вниз, т.к. пространство над ним занимают остальные блоки.

Как сделать так чтобы остальные блоки разворачивались, а третий оставался в начале экрана?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как то так http://jsfiddle.net/bNEQZ/

Comment: Да, это практически то что нужно, только необходимо что третий блок не прыгал совсем, оставался на месте. Я придумал такой вариант: http://jsfiddle.net/bNEQZ/4/

Но тут есть один баг, при скроллинге, если при закрытых блоках поднять блок вверх и из такого положения открывать остальные блоки, то виднеется полоса верхнего открывающегося блока.

Как вариант может быть есть какой-то метод сказать браузеру просто открывать блоки вверх?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bNEQZ/5/ — пойдет?

Answer (score 0):

Спозиционируй блоки с css-свойством "`position:absolute`".

Answer (score 0):

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/
Оно?

Comment: Нет, вот приблизительно то что нужно. http://jsfiddle.net/bNEQZ/4/

Answer (score 0):

Почему вы не хотите сделать accordion? Это же почти готовые решение, просто со стилями переключателей подразобраться, чтоб не мешали